# XML Response returned has White Space

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to fix an error for a friend in his site that someone else has written and I am having a real hard time with one of these errors. There is functionality to check wether a user can use a username via AJAX, the response is XML. However, the XML returned has an error in it.

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location: moz-nullprincipal:{17ec3adb-5ee9-437a-b047-8910f6faa55c} Line Number 2, Column 1:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajaxResponse><cunamemsg>1</cunamemsg></aj...
^
```

When I look at the actual response, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajaxResponse><cunamemsg>1</cunamemsg></ajaxResponse>
```

It has a white line at the top, which I am guessing is causing the JS error in conjunction:

```
cunameresult.getElementsByTagName(

if(cunameresult.getElementsByTagName('cunamemsg').item(0).firstChild.data==0)
```

To be honest, I have no idea what else to check. I've checked each PHP script referenced for any white space.

Is it possible that PHP notices can cause the XML returned to have an extra line? There are quite a few PHP notices and warnings being logged that are within the same script but they refer to variables being un-initialised.

Thanks all for any help on this and what direction to take to find a solution.

Comment: What is the PHP source code generating the XML? Are you sure it has no empty line before the `<?php`?

Comment: I was going to say yes, but I tripple checked and found a space after one of the scripts required. That was a waste of an hour! Thanks Pekka for prompting a check again! Maybe you can add an answer so I can close this question! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have no white space before the opening `<?php` or anywhere in the included PHP scripts - it would be visible in the XML result as well.

Comment: Thanks, this will save someone some time, I'm sure!